# Windows 8 cli to take screenshots

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface

I'm using boxcutter and take screenshots via command line. I want a loop that runs for 4 hours and takes screenshots every 10 seconds. I CAN NOT get a .bat to do this.  First, I can't figure out how to make the script sleep for 10 seconds. Below is my code and no matter what variation I try my prompt just flashes quickly and is gone, yes I have used some choice words on this gem.

```
ECHO ON
for /l %i in (1,1,10) do
E:\boxcutter\boxcutter.exe -f E:\screenshots\%i.png
ping -n 10 someserver.com
done

pause
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,1440) do (
    E:\boxcutter\boxcutter.exe -f E:\screenshots\%%i.png
    ping -n 10 localhost>nul
)
pause
```

This will take screenshots 10 seconds apart for 1440 iterations (which is 4 hours). Note that I doubled the percent signs in the `for` loop since this is running in a batch file, and I corrected the syntax for `for...do...`

You'll find it much easier to troubleshoot batch files if you open a command prompt and run them from there rather than double-clicking them from Windows Explorer.  The command prompt will stay open rather than flashing briefly and disappearing.